# How to update content (show/hide) with renderPartial Yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

How do I can update the content within the block "div" which is currently selected combo box?

I've created an action like this :

```
public function actionDetail()
{
    $sql = "
    SELECT
        tbl_quotation_order.id_quo
        , tbl_quotation_order.no_quo
        , tbl_produk.nama_produk
        , tbl_detail_quo.qty
        , tbl_detail_quo.harga_indo_after
        , tbl_detail_quo.harga_dolar_after
        , tbl_pemasok.nama_pemasok
    FROM
        tbl_quotation_order
        INNER JOIN tbl_detail_quo 
            ON (tbl_quotation_order.id_detil_quo = tbl_detail_quo.id_quo_fk)
        INNER JOIN tbl_produk 
            ON (tbl_detail_quo.id_produk = tbl_produk.id_produk)
        INNER JOIN tbl_pemasok 
            ON (tbl_produk.id_pemasok = tbl_pemasok.id_pemasok)
    WHERE tbl_quotation_order.id_quo='20'";

    $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql);
    $this->render('_detail',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

When accessed will result in the display :
[image]

I want to display a data table containing the data within :

```
<div id="detailQuo" style="display:none;">

</div>
```

My jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#SelesOrder_id_quo").change(function() {
        //Call controller and show the table
        $("#detailQuo").show();
    });
});
```

I need a solution to update a different view inside my div on a click event.

Thanks

Comment: question is unclear, do you want to update the combobox using ajax? Or are you asking how to generate a combobox?

Comment: @themosquitokiller No...I want to `show` div with id `detailQuo`. When I change the selection in the combo box, then I want to bring up the table into the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML -

```
<div id="detailQuo" style="display:none;">
  <?php $this->renderPartial('//<controllername>/_detail',array('pageload'=>true)); ?>
</div>
```

Controller function ->

```
public function actionDetail()
{
    $sql = "
    SELECT
        tbl_quotation_order.id_quo
        , tbl_quotation_order.no_quo
        , tbl_produk.nama_produk
        , tbl_detail_quo.qty
        , tbl_detail_quo.harga_indo_after
        , tbl_detail_quo.harga_dolar_after
        , tbl_pemasok.nama_pemasok
    FROM
        tbl_quotation_order
        INNER JOIN tbl_detail_quo 
            ON (tbl_quotation_order.id_detil_quo = tbl_detail_quo.id_quo_fk)
        INNER JOIN tbl_produk 
            ON (tbl_detail_quo.id_produk = tbl_produk.id_produk)
        INNER JOIN tbl_pemasok 
            ON (tbl_produk.id_pemasok = tbl_pemasok.id_pemasok)
    WHERE tbl_quotation_order.id_quo='20'";

    $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql);
    $this->renderPartial('_detail',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

**_detail.php**
detect page load on `$pageload=true` and load nothing - while load the stuff you need via ajax in the `else` case